# Disney BRDF - where is metallic factor input into BRDF?

Tags: shaders, graphics, pbr

Burley states about *metallic* parameter:

"This is a linear blend between two different models. ..."

What are the two models? I can't see this described in the Frostbite or the Unreal papers either.

Is it simply a blend between the diffuse and specular terms or a scaling factor on the specular term?

[Disney Paper](https://disney-animation.s3.amazonaws.com/library/s2012_pbs_disney_brdf_notes_v2.pdf)

Comment: Note there is a good discussion of this issue here: http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/2285/how-to-properly-combine-the-diffuse-and-specular-terms?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, the answer seems to be right there in the continuation of that line:

> **metallic** - the metallic-ness (0 = dielectric, 1 = metallic). This is a
>   linear blend between two different models. *The metallic model has no
>   diffuse component and also has a tinted incident specular, equal to
>   the base color.*

(With the implication that the dielectric model is defined by *not* having those specific traits)

ie...

Dielectric Model:

- Has diffuse component
- Incident specular is not tinted

Metallic Model:

- Diffuse component = 0
- Incident specular is tinted by base colour